# Setting 90days difference between the first date selected

Tags: date-range, daterangepicker

I have a requirement of setting date ranges 
t1 I select a date and the t2 date must be within 90 days of the selected date in t1.

pls help me achieve this thanks

heres my part of javascript that I have tried

```
<%-- <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtOnDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtAppDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtAppDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+90D",
        numberOfMonths: 1,

    });  
});
</script>--%>
```

the issue that I am facing in the above script is when I select the end date it doesn't change according to the 1st textbox selected date. it remains the same date irrespective of the date selected in the ttxtbox1
 please help

Comment: You should play with this: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=-10d&endDate=%2B90d&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .change() to edit the value

eg:

`$("#txtOnDate").change({
    $("#txtAppDate").val = date + 90;
});`